# Blazor render Identity UI on the server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

The default setting seems to be that the new Blazor Identity UI pages are static pages.
I can't set them to @rendermode InteractiveServer. I can set individual components I have created to rendermode=InteractiveServer but then I can't use Components that uses RenderFragments and similar.

Is there a way to run the login page, register page and similar as InteractiveServer?

How to recreate:

- Create a new Blazor Web app (.Net 8).
- Select Authentication Type Individual accounts and Interactive render mode to Auto (Server and WebAssembly).
- Add @rendermode InteractiveServer to the Login page

Write a simple button component where you add RenderFragment ChildComponent as a Parameter. Then exchange the login botton at the page with the one you wrote.

Comment: They aren't designed to be interactive.

Comment: So there it no way to change this?

Comment: I think you need to write it yourself.